# I'm using a vlookup formula and wanting it to =i6 if no data is found in the tables

Tags: vlookup

the vlook up are working but i want it to =i6 if no data is found in the look ups
here is the formula I'm using:

```
=UPPER(IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(O6,'Wipedrive Report'!A:F,4,FALSE)),IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(O6,'Asset Capture'!A:F,5,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(O6,'Asset Capture'!A:F,5,FALSE)),VLOOKUP(O6,'Wipedrive Report'!A:F,4,FALSE)))
```

any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Where a properly constructed VLOOKUP function fails to find a compliant value the result to be expected is `#N/A`. If a default value, such as obtained from cell I6 or to be shown as `"=i6"`, is to be returned instead of the error indicated, the VLOOKUP function may be wrapped in an [IFERROR](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Iferror.html) function.

The workings of IFERROR are equivalent to [ISERROR](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-iserror-function) inside an [IF](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-if-function) function. This is suitable for Excel versions prior to the introduction of IFERROR with Excel 2007, and may demonstrate the working of IFERROR, since that is effectively only a more concise form.

Hence:

```
=IFERROR(<yourformula>,I6)
```

or depending on your requirement, perhaps:

```
=IFERROR(<yourformula>,"=i6")
```

The pre-Excel 2007 version:

```
=IF(ISERROR(<yourformula>,<I6 or "-i6" to suit>,<yourformula>)
```